# Doctrine wont generate columns for properites inherited from mapped super class

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a mapped super class and two entities that extend that base class. I followed [this docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html), but when I run `bin/console doctrine:schema:update` both of my entities are generated only with the properties declared on the entity itself but not the ones declared in the mapped super class. What am I missing or doing wrong?

mapped super class:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass(repositoryClass="Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository")
 */
class Comment {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text", length=500)
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    // setters and getters...
}
```

extending entities:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Model\Comment;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="component_comment")
 */
class ComponentComment extends Comment {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ComponentComment", inversedBy="replies")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="reply_to", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $replyTo;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ComponentComment", mappedBy="replyTo")
     */
    private $replies;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Component", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="component", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $targetComponent;

    // setters and getters...

}
```

and

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Model\Comment;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="food_comment")
 */
class FoodComment extends Comment {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FoodComment", inversedBy="replies")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="reply_to", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $replyTo;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FoodComment", mappedBy="replyTo")
     */
    private $replies;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Food", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="food", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $targetFood;

    // setters and getters...
}
```

And my corresponding database tables look like:

```
CREATE TABLE `component_comment` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `reply_to` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `component` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_2478D345E2B0FBEB` (`reply_to`),
  KEY `IDX_2478D34549FEA157` (`component`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_2478D34549FEA157` FOREIGN KEY (`component`) REFERENCES `component` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_2478D345E2B0FBEB` FOREIGN KEY (`reply_to`) REFERENCES `component_comment` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `food_comment` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `reply_to` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `food` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_DBEB8E54E2B0FBEB` (`reply_to`),
  KEY `IDX_DBEB8E54D43829F7` (`food`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_DBEB8E54D43829F7` FOREIGN KEY (`food`) REFERENCES `food` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_DBEB8E54E2B0FBEB` FOREIGN KEY (`reply_to`) REFERENCES `food_comment` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

The columns from common properties inherited from the `Comment` parent class are missing. Why is wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you having any other Entities with relations to your mapped superclass `Comment` ?

Comment: I don't think you can have a ManyToOne (or OneToMany) relationship defined in your MappedSuperClass.

Comment: Beside the Author there are no other Entities related to the mapped superclass itself. As the documentation says "persistent relationships defined by a mapped superclass must be unidirectional (with an owning side only). This means that One-To-Many associations are not possible on a mapped superclass at all. " Thats correct I cant have ManyToOne relation, but it is strange, that doctrine instead giving a warning or error, simply ignores the mapped superclass

Answer (score 2):

I've fond an other solution that fits better my requirements, but I think I've figured out. I haven't tested it but very likely the problem is that the mapped super class has private properties instead of protected ones. So although they were mapped properly, the sub classes didn't inherit neither the properties nor the mappings belonging to them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should place the mapped superclass under AppBundle/Entity